# starting a system with constraints using systemd

Tags: linux, process, systemd

I have a large system that consists of multiple processes and docker containers. I would like to have the system initialized by systemd but I have several constraints between the processes:

1. There should be a specific starting order to the processes
2. Each process should finish initializing before the next one starts
3. In case that one of the processes falls some of the processes should be re-initialized in the same order according to constraint number 1
4. I should be able to start all the system (all the processes) and stop it with one command.

I have read several tutorials on how to work with systemd:

- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-systemd-units-and-unit-files
- https://coreos.com/docs/launching-containers/launching/getting-started-with-systemd/
- And more

But how to work with targets and implement a proper service hierarchy is still a mystery to me. can anyone please suggest a better tutorial or explain it to me somehow? Or if I am wrong and it's impossible incorporate all of my constraints using systemd please say so and explain.

Thanks,

Comment: systemd is perfectly capable of ordering startup of tasks. What is the problem you are having?

Comment: There isn't really a specific problem, I was able to acquire some of the requirements I mentioned but it seems like I didn't really implemented them like I should have and I have no real way of knowing.